# UWP "file in use error" on brand new file

Tags: c#, uwp

I got some intermit exceptions to write texts to a brand new file in one of my UWP application. The sample codes look like

```
var myFolder = await GetFolder("MyFolderName");
var fileName = $"{random}-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.xml";
var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(myFile, "some content");

private static async Task<StorageFolder> GetFolder(string folderName)
{
    var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

    var possibleFolder = await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync(folderName);
    if (possibleFolder == null)
    {
        await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName);
    }

    var folder = await storageFolder.GetFolderAsync(folderName);

    return folder;
}
```

The exception is thrown on line `await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(myFile, "some content");` with the following details

> System.IO.FileLoadException: The process cannot access the file
>   because it is being used by another process.
>
> The file is in use. Please close the file before continuing.    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at MyClass.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

I really don't get, how can a brand new file being used already?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code in a blank project and it works perfectly fine.

May it be possible that you are calling this method from multiple threads at once? If yes, you should consider using a `Semaphore` or `lock` to prevent multiple threads from accessing the section at once.

Also, `random` may not be completely random. If you create multiple instances of the `Random` class at the same time, it is very possible that you will get the same values when first queried, because it is just pseudo-random. The best approach is to create just one, shared instance of the class.

Put together:

```
private static Random _randomizer = new Random();

public async Task CreateFileAsync()
{        
    var random = 0;
    lock ( _randomizer )
    {
       random = _randomizer.Next();
    }

    var myFolder = await GetFolder("MyFolderName");
    var fileName = $"{random}-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.xml";
    var myFile = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(myFile, "some content");

    async Task<StorageFolder> GetFolder(string folderName)
    {
        var storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        var possibleFolder = await storageFolder.TryGetItemAsync(folderName);
        if (possibleFolder == null)
        {
            await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName);
        }

        var folder = await storageFolder.GetFolderAsync(folderName);

        return folder;
    }            
}
```

Comment: My code is actually inside a `ExtendedExecutionSession` with callback from GPS sensor, the interval should only be once every a while. I don't think concurrency is an issue. An I also wrapped my code in `Polly` for auto retry and eventually I get it done.